# Смена содержимого Div

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript

Добрый день! Вот такая задачка у меня есть у меня такой див к примеру

```
 <div>
   <form action='update_user.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
     Изменить аватар:<br>
     Изображение должно быть формата jpg, gif или png. <br>
     <input type="FILE" name="fupload">
     <input type='submit' name='submit' value='изменить'>
   </form>
 </div>
```

и есть две ссылки на запуск функции вот такие

```
 <div class="classnewsbg">
   <a href="javascript:Swapsettings('osnov')">Основные настройки</a>
 </div>
 <div class="classnewsbg">
   <a href="javascript:Swapsettings('personal')">Персональные настройки</a>
 </div>
```

суть задачи в том, чтобы содержание Дива с формой при клике на ссылку менялось на другое, скажем, другую форму

пробовал вот так

```
<script src="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Swapsettings(swapto) {
        if (swapto == 'osnov') {
            $(".settings").replaceWith("<div class='settings'><?php   require_once('phpscripts/ossettings.php');?></div>"); }
        else if (swapto == 'personal') {
            $(".settings").replaceWith("<div class='settings'>Тут хтмл код с формой  </div>"); 
        }
    }
</script>
```

Но ни вставка готового кода в функцию ни вставка кода из файла не помогают. Подскажите, как лучше сделать?

Comment: У вас не прописан класс дива с формой. Хотя, в этой ситуации лучше было бы использовать id.

Comment: Тогда вопрос, нехрена вам jQuery, если вы ищете елементы с помощью getElementById ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

А спасибо решил по другому уже - через getelement by id display none/block

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('divForm').innerHTML = document.getElementById('kod1').innerText;
}

function Swapsettings(swapto) {
    if (swapto == 'osnov') {
        document.getElementById('divForm').innerHTML = document.getElementById('kod1').innerText;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('divForm').innerHTML = document.getElementById('kod2').innerText;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="divForm"></div>
<br>
<div class="classnewsbg">
    <a href="javascript:Swapsettings('osnov');">Основные настройки</a>
</div>
<div class="classnewsbg">
    <a href="javascript:Swapsettings('personal');">Персональные настройки</a>
</div>

<div style="display: none;">
    <textarea id="kod1"><form action='update_user.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Изменить аватар:<br> Изображение должно быть формата jpg, gif или png. <br>
        <input type="FILE" name="fupload">
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='изменить'>
    </form></textarea>
    <textarea id="kod2"><form action='update_foto.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        Изменить фотографию:<br> Изображение должно быть формата jpg, gif или png. <br>
        <input type="FILE" name="fupload">
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='изменить'>
    </form></textarea>
</div>
```